# I would like to achieve a two column checkout page

Tags: css

[image: checkout image]I would like to achieve a two column checkout instead of three as seen in the image, how can i achieve that, below is the code i used to customize my css.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
#customer_details{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
#order_review_heading{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
#order_review{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.woocommerce table.shop_table td{
    width: 50%;
}
.woocommerce .col2-set .col-1, .woocommerce-page .col2-set .col-1,
.woocommerce .col2-set .col-2, .woocommerce-page .col2-set .col-2{
    width: 100%;
}
```

}

Comment: This is more of a CSS question than it is Wordpress.  Try asking on http://stackoverflow.com - You have what you need there in the CSS, just play with the values in your browser's inspector.

Comment: What's the HTML look like? Without this it's difficult to figure out what your CSS does. Also, when you tried this, what went wrong?

Comment: https://www.atnjsignalbooster.com/checkout-2/ here is the link to the checkout, I have managed to make two columns, but I am still having an issue. Kindly help me out